# How to always have spaces around \circ?

Tags: spacing, symbols

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\op{\mathrel{\circ}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$a = \op b$\\
$c \op d$
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to have an operator as `\circ`, and I want it to be always surrounded by spaces. However, this is what I'm getting (no space between `=` and the circle):

[image]

Comment: If you want an operator, then `\mathrel` is definitely the wrong choice.

Comment: @egreg what is a better choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX has several types of math atoms:

- **Ord** `\mathord`
- **Op** `\mathop`
- **Bin** `\mathbin`
- **Rel** `\mathrel`
- **Open** `\mathopen`
- **Close** `\mathclose`
- **Punct** `\mathpunct`
- **Inner** `\mathinner`

The rules for spacing between atoms in these classes is explained by this table from TeX by Topic, page 205 (entries in parentheses mean that the space is only inserted in `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`).

[image]

According to the rules, denoting by T a thick space and by t a thin space, your code produces

a T = ◦ T b
c T ◦ T b

If you want an “operator”, then `\mathop` should be the choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\op{\mathop{\circ}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

$a = \op b$

$c \op d$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this code you get

a T = T ◦ t b
c t d

Of course you're not using `\circ` for function composition, are you?

Comment: Indeed, I am using `\circ` for function composition. Why?)

Comment: @yegor256 How would a reader distinguish between the two uses?

Comment: I'm using `x = \circ \{ f_1, f_2, ... f_n \}` to denote a composition of a set of functions. Does it make sense?

Comment: @yegor256 Not much, I'd say.

Comment: What would be a better notation for this? I have a set of functions defined with the use of set-builder notation and I need to denote the composition of them all.